# Especially in X "class" or "classes"?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, grammatical-number

I'm writing a document and am confused whether I should write "class" singular or "classes" plural. Grammar online checker seems to allow both. What is the reasoning behind?

> especially in reading and grammar class.

or

> especially in reading and grammar classes.

Comment: It would help to know the context of this sentence fragment.

Comment: The whole sentence is: "Task Based Language Teaching has been gradually adopted by English Teachers in the Country, especially in reading and grammar class."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues here.

(1) Which sense of 'class' is intended here?

> - (a) a group of students who are taught together at school, college, or university:
>
> ...
>
> *She gave the whole class extra homework for a week.*
>
> [*John is not in my maths class.*]
>
> [*John and Jill are in different classes.*]

or

> - (b) a period of time in which students are taught something:
>
> ...
>
> *I missed my aerobics class yesterday.*
>
> [*John missed his maths class yesterday.*]
>
> [John has missed all his maths classes this week.]

[[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/class), with added examples]

Obviously, both senses are used in count usages.

(2) Are reading classes and grammar classes distinct entities, or are 'reading and grammar classes' (like *health and safety lectures*) single entities?

(3) With count usages, the distributive singular is quite often a complication (so "Gentlemen, on your way home, buy your **wife** a bunch of roses" is fine).

............................

**(1)** We'll assume CE sense 1b, the teaching period, as being more likely, though the ambiguity needs resolving.

**(2)** We'll assume that reading periods/classes and grammar periods are distinct.

**(3)** Here, though (as your grammar checker validates) the distributive singular is available, probably reflecting sense 1a but almost synonymous with 'course', I'd feel more comfortable with the formally obvious plural, *classes*. In the UK, 'especially in reading and grammar lesson' would be unacceptable, though 'especially in a reading or a grammar lesson' would be fine. As would 'especially in reading or grammar lessons'.